# Why is tensorflow looking for cuda10.1 while cuda 10.0 installed?

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia

I am on Ubuntu 18.04. And output of following commands:

```
nvidia-smi
Fri Dec  4 11:35:09 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.87.01    Driver Version: 418.87.01    CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla M40           On   | 00000000:00:08.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   59C    P0   146W / 250W |  11724MiB / 12215MiB |    100%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130

dpkg -l | grep cuda
ii  cuda-command-line-tools-10-0                          10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA command-line tools
ii  cuda-compat-10-0                                      410.104-1                         amd64        CUDA Compatibility Platform
ii  cuda-cublas-10-0                                      10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUBLAS native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-cudart-10-0                                      10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA Runtime native Libraries
ii  cuda-cudart-dev-10-0                                  10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA Runtime native dev links, headers
ii  cuda-cufft-10-0                                       10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUFFT native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-cuobjdump-10-0                                   10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA cuobjdump
ii  cuda-cupti-10-0                                       10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA profiling tools interface.
ii  cuda-curand-10-0                                      10.0.130-1                        amd64        CURAND native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-cusolver-10-0                                    10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA solver native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-cusparse-10-0                                    10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUSPARSE native runtime libraries
ii  cuda-driver-dev-10-0                                  10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA Driver native dev stub library
ii  cuda-gdb-10-0                                         10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA-GDB
ii  cuda-gpu-library-advisor-10-0                         10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA GPU Library Advisor.
ii  cuda-license-10-0                                     10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA licenses
ii  cuda-memcheck-10-0                                    10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA-MEMCHECK
ii  cuda-misc-headers-10-0                                10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA miscellaneous headers
ii  cuda-nvcc-10-0                                        10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA nvcc
ii  cuda-nvdisasm-10-0                                    10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA disassembler
ii  cuda-nvprof-10-0                                      10.0.130-1                        amd64        CUDA Profiler tools
ii  cuda-nvtx-10-0                                        10.0.130-1                        amd64        NVIDIA Tools Extension
ii  cuda-repo-ubuntu1804                                  10.1.243-1                        amd64        cuda repository configuration files
ii  libcudnn7                                             7.4.1.5-1+cuda10.0                amd64        cuDNN runtime libraries
ii  libnvinfer5                                           5.0.2-1+cuda10.0                  amd64        TensorRT runtime libraries
ii  nvinfer-runtime-trt-repo-ubuntu1804-5.0.2-ga-cuda10.0 1-1                               amd64        nvinfer-runtime-trt repository configuration files
```

So I have cuda10.0 installed. I also set up the path:

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But then why does it gives this error? It looks for cuda10.1, instead of cuda10.0?

```
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
2020-12-04 11:37:43.929779: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
2020-12-04 11:37:43.929830: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2.3.1
```

Comment: You must use the version of CUDA which tensorflow was built against. This is a non-negotiable requirement. In this case that is 10.1

Comment: @talonmies Does the error message mean the tensorflow is built against cuda 10.1? In that case, if I downgrade tensorflow version, the error message will be away?

Comment: As I said in my comment, yes that means your tensorflow was built against and requires 10.1. As for downgrading I have no idea. You need to use a version built against CUDA 10.0 if that is what you have installed. It may not be a downgrade. That is for you to determine.

Comment: I also suggest upgrading CUDA to 10.1 instead of downgrading TF. Besides the current question it will save you from other incompatibility situations.

Comment: OR if you are somehow unable to update CUDA you are able to build TF of needed version against your CUDA version. But still @PoeDator 's advice is most preferable.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Tensorflow tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) from `TF 2.1` to `TF 2.3`, it required `CUDA 10.1` version, hence you received above error.

If you would like to use `CUDA 10.0`, then compatible versions are `TF_GPU 1.15` and `TF 2.0`.

As rightly suggested by  Poe Dator, you can upgrade to `CUDA 10.1` instead of `tensorflow downgrading`. Because latest versions addressed many of the performance issues.